# Why do we only define rational functions on irreducible algebraic sets (varieties)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to self-study algebraic geometry with these notes and I am trying to understand why we only define rational maps on irreducible algebraic sets (we call them varieties in these notes).

[https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~cb496/ag2007-final.pdf](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Ecb496/ag2007-final.pdf)

[image]

So I understand if we have an irreducible algebraic set, then we have a coordinate ring which is an integral domain so we can form its field into fractions. However, for these notes, we are not really defining them like that. Regular functions and rational functions are not elements of some polynomial ring in the sense that they are not just formal objects, but they are actually defined as functions. Now having read other text, I know there is actually an isomorphism between these formal objects and actual functions, but since we have defined them to be actual functions in these notes, why is it that we don't or do not want to apply the definition of a rational function to algebraic sets even if they are reducible?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. May I ask how our addition is defined in this case since we are kinda summing equivalence classes. Do we just look at the sum over the intersection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is irreducible then any non-empty open subset is dense. This is needed to make that relation, which is supposed to be an equivalence, transitive (and technically the definition should specify the open sets to be non-empty since as stated any $(\phi, U)$ is equivalent to the empty function on the empty set).

If $X = Y \cap Z$ with $Y$ and $Z$ proper closed subsets, consider $f$ the constant $0$ function, $g$ the $0$ function on $X - Y$ and $h$ the constant $1$ function on $X - Z$. Then $f$ is equivalent to $g$ and $g$ is equivalent to $h$ but $f$ is not equivalent to $h$.